# What is a summary of each masechta in shas?

Tags: talmud-gemara

I would like to know what each masechta deals with. In a couple of sentences per tractate, can we have a summary of each?

Comment: check daf yomi forum.
for example: pesachim is here
https://dafyomi.co.il/pesachim/ps-in-biblio.htm

Comment: Hi Yishai, good to have you here! Have you checked Wikipedia? Usually they have a very brief summary for each tractate taken from the Jewish Encyclopedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berakhot_(tractate)#Structure_and_content

Answer (score 10):

Praise be the Lord
Food to poor award
Doubtful tithes just to be sure
Mixing seed's a no
Seventh year don't grow
Heave offerings must stay pure
One tenth to Levi's kin
Another to Jerusalem
From each dough a loaf apart
Three years per tree
First fruits I can see
Weekly rests we surely guard
Defining the domains
Annual paschal lambs
Half a coin the Temple's dued
Day of atonement
Tabernacles' tent
Rest on the holidays except food
Lunar months and years
Fasting with our tears
Esther's tale is read aloud for all
Intermediate restrictings
Festival offerings
Levirs keep the family whole
Marriage contracts
Vows and retracts
Nazarite's who can't drink wine
Suspicion of affair
Divorce clears the air
Though the marriage started fine
Torts and injuries
Contracts and fees
Real estate transactions and inheritance
Order in the court
Or a whipping sport
Give your word in place of evidence
Tell us what you learned
Foreign idols burned
Teachers have the tradition of wisdom
All can be mistaken
From animal taken
Or from plants consecrate some
Mundane slaughter
Firstborns you offer
Evaluate and donate to the treasury
Switching animals
Punish radicals
Stealing holy items as treachery
Temple dimensions
Orderly processions
Fixing you up after mixing up birds
Impure sorts of vessels
Death's the highest level
Leprosy received for misspoken words
A purifying cow
Clean foods how
Dipping in the natural water seas
Feminine impurify
Foods not staying dry
Levels of discharges of disease
Till sunset still demands
Abluting both hands
Plant connections ending these

Comment: PTIJ is already on?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's really something. Nicely done.